# AngularJS not selecting value

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.5.6. The ng-app and ng-controller are set up properly. My  options are

```
$scope.apis =[
            {'id':0, 'apiUrl':'https://api0.com', 'label':'Label0'},
            {'id':1, 'apiUrl':'https://api1.com', 'label':'Label1'},
            {'id':2, 'apiUrl':'https://api2.com', 'label':'Label2'},
            {'id':3, 'apiUrl':'https://api3.com','label':'Label3'}
        ];

$scope.selectedApi = $scope.apis[1];// default
```

And in my select tag if I declare it as:

```
<select ng-model="selectedApi" ng-options="x.apiUrl as x.label for x in apis">
```

then each option renders like this (for example, Label1):

```
<option label="Label1" value="string:https://api1.com">Label1</option>
```

But the value is not selected as I console.log() my selection in an event handler, it shows the selected value is `undefined`. What is the reason?

Comment: *AngularJS 3.2.1*: there is no such thing.

Comment: Since ng-options is `x.apiUrl as ...`, the selected value should be an apiUrl, not an api. If you want the model (i.e. the selectedApi) to be an api, then ng-options should be `x as ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedApi" ng-options="x as x.label for x in apis"></select>
```

In this case `selectedApi` is an object (regards to initial state)

<kbd>[Demo in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NWjLhrxsTXHpIKjOZmLe?p=preview)</kbd>